# How to make .py files open directly into Idle

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm not sure what I've done but for a moment my .py files kept asking me what to open them in. They used to open straight into Idle, but now I can't get that back. I have to keep right-clicking and selecting "Edit with Idle". Does anyone know how I can get it back to opening straight into Idle.

I have looked at other sources and they told me to set the default program to a batch file in

```
C:\Python32\Lib\idlelib
```

but that opens the .py file and a blank file. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

right click > open with... >  choose default program.   select idle and make sure the box to always open with is checked

I had to change my idle.bat to get it to work

```
@echo off
pythonw C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

it will open whatever you double clicked as well as a shell

Comment: Bah! you beat me this time

Comment: I don't have an application called Idle, all I seem to have is a batch file :(

Comment: ok I take back my snarky comment and answer.. apparently its not that straightforward for idle ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is there any way to make it so the .py files have an icon. Looks super ugly just as a file?

Comment: im sure there is ... but its probably more trouble than its worth ... http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/change-icon-bat-file-windows-7/ ... it looks like you will need to change the bat file into an executable and then set its icon ... then redo the open with step

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the `.py` file and click on the `Change` button right next to `Opens With`. Change the application to IDLE and you're done!