# Can't open .py file in Python idle

Tags: python, pycharm, python-idle, file-type

I am new to programming. I was writing on idle that comes with python, but then I decided to download PyCharm. I didn't like it so i deleted it. Some files that I already saved became PyCharm file types and I can't open them in idle that comes with Python. I tried changing the default app for the file type, but I didn't see idle there. What should I do? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5k3G.png)

Comment: This appears to be (just as you suspect) a file association issue.  IDLE might not appear in the association selection, perhaps browse to it.  Or (if on Win) update the registry to point to the IDLE exe.  Additionally, [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) is another nice IDE, and much lighter weight than PyCharm.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I am on windows, I don't really understand how and where do I have to update the registry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Python IDLE as Default Program to Open .py Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24988880/6045800)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make .py files open directly into Idle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21418727/6045800)

Comment: Might also be relevant to your case: [Edit with IDLE disappeared for .py files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34319456/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

Double clicking on the .py files usually runs the Python program. But if you always want to open .py files via IDLE when you double click, follow the below steps:

Right click on the python file and select Open with and select -> Look for other apps in the PC

[image]

and then navigate to your Python installed location. Under that navigate to \Lib\idlelib\ and then select **idle.bat**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are those python files? If that's the case, Right click, open with IDLE. The other suggestion is to rename the files with `.py` extensions to mark them as python files. In that way, the files will automatically be associated with IDLE.

Comment: When you change a file's extension, you change the way programs on your computer read the file. The problem is, changing the file extension does not change the file type. In other words, when you change a file's extension, it does not change the way the file is formatted.

Comment: Also, most likely the files are already `.py` files. Windows doesn't show file extensions by default. Can easily be turned on in the directory View settings...